# Solving $7[x]+23\{x\}=191$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

> For every real number $x$, $[x]$ denotes the largest integer less than
>   or equal to $x$ and $\{x\}=x-[x]$.
>
> The number of real solutions of
>
> $$7[x]+23\{x\}=191$$ is
>
> (a) 0 $\quad$ (b) 1 $\quad$ (c) 2 $\quad$ (d) 3

**I solved it like this:**

$$7[x]+23\{x\}=191$$

$$7(x-\{x\})+23\{x\}=191$$

$$7x+16\{x\}=191$$

Now,

$$0 \leq \{x\} < 1$$

$$0 \leq 16\{x\} < 16$$

$$0 \leq 191-7x < 1$$

$$-16 < 7x-191 \leq 0$$

$$175 < 7x \leq 191$$

$$\frac{175}{7} < x \leq \frac{191}{7}$$

$$25 < x \leq 27.2857$$

But $x=26$ doesn't satisfy given equation. Answer given is $(d)$ $3$.

I don't understand where I'm wrong.

A hint will be of great help.

Please don't provide complete solution.

Sorry for poor LaTeX.

Comment: Put backslashes in front of your curly brackets so you can leave them inside the dollar signs.  I fixed a few of them.

Comment: Thanks @GregoryGrant I'm new to LaTeX.

Comment: I rather than getting rid of $[x]$, keep it. You have $7m + 23y = 191$, where $m$ is an integer. This means that $23y$  must also be an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work with $[x]$ and not $x$, try
$$0≤ \{x\} <1$$

$$0≤ 23\{x\} <23$$

$$0≤191−7[x]<23$$

$$−23<7[x]−191≤0$$

$$168<7[x]≤191$$

$$168/7<[x]≤191/7$$

$$24<[x]≤27.2857$$

So your answers are some $x$ with $[x]$ = $25$, $26$ or $27$

The $\{x\}$ part is just $\frac{(191 - 7[x])}{23}$

then :)

Comment: btw, just for info: [x] is just rounding, if you wanna round down, you have to use |_ _|, you can look for the symbol yourself (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions first paragraph)

Comment: The correct symbols are available as `\lfloor \rfloor`, looking like this: $\lfloor x \rfloor$

Answer (score 2):

$$0\le\{x\}<1\implies0\le23\{x\}<23$$

$$\implies0\le191-7[x]<23\iff0\ge7[x]-191>-23$$

$$\iff28>191/7\ge[x]>(191-23)/7=24$$

So, $[x]$ can be $25,26,27$

Comment: You just found values for $[x]$, not for $x$, you should continue....

Comment: But I need to find the number of real solutions i.e. $x$ not $[x]$ @LabBhattacharjee or Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: Ok! got it There will be some $\{x\}$ which when put together with $[x]=25$ or $26$ or $27$ will give us the desired solution.

Comment: @Integrator, Nice to see your response

Answer (score 2):

Fractional part of x , $\{x\}$ must be of the form $\frac{y}{23}$. Thus, write $x = z + \frac{y}{23}$ where $z = [x]$ and $y<23$ and $y,z$ are integers. Thus, $7z + y = 191$. 
$$191 \equiv 2 \mod 7$$
Thus, $y \equiv 2 \mod 7$. Number of such values of $y$ that are less than 23 are just 3 (2,9,16).

Comment: I haven't studied stuff like $$191 \equiv 2 \mod 7$$
 @Ojas. Can you please explain it a bit or direct me to some good source to study.

Comment: It just means that 191 leaves a remainder of 2 when divided by 7. And for both sides of the equation to be equal, y should also leave a remainder of 2 when divided by 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple solutions,
Hope it's help

$\mathrm{7}\left[{x}\right]+\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}=\mathrm{191} \\ $
$\left[{x}\right]=\mathrm{27}+\frac{\mathrm{2}−\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}}{\mathrm{7}}\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \\ $
$\frac{\mathrm{2}−\mathrm{23}\left\{{x}\right\}}{\mathrm{7}}={k}\in{Z} \\ $
$\frac{\mathrm{2}−\mathrm{7}{k}}{\mathrm{23}}=\left\{{x}\right\}\in\left[\mathrm{0},\mathrm{1}\right) \\ $
${k}\in\left\{\mathrm{0},-\mathrm{1},-\mathrm{2}\right\}\Rightarrow{n}\left({k}\right)=\mathrm{3} \\ $